# Using Content Resolver to query a list of media that matches a list of media Id

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, storage

I want to get a list of songs that matches a list of media Id's using content Resolver.

E.G

```
SELECT FROM AUDIO WHERE _id = {223, 22, 38, 90}.
```

So this should return a list of medias with the respective Id's, So I'll get media 223, media 22, media 38 and media 90

I am doing something like this, but it is returning an empty list.

```
private var selectionArgs = ArrayList<Long>()

private val projection = arrayOf(
    MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
)
private fun getColumnIndex(cursor: Cursor, columnName: String): Int{
    return cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName)
}
fun getSongsInPlaylist(songIds: List<Long>): List<Songs> {
    val selection = "${MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID} = ?"
    selectionArgs = songIds as ArrayList<Long>

 val songList =  mutableListOf<Songs>()

    val collection = Utility.sdk29AndUp {
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)
    } ?:  MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

    //Get songs from provider
    context.contentResolver.query(
        collection,
        projection,
        selection,
        arrayOf(selectionArgs.toTypedArray().toString()),
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER //Sort in alphabetical order based on 
  display name.
    ).use { cursor ->
        if (cursor?.moveToFirst() == true) {
            do {
            ..........
       }

  songList.add(
  Songs(
  mediaId = id,
  title = truncatedTitle,
  subtitle = truncatedArtisteName,                 
  )
  )
  } while (cursor.moveToNext())
        }
    }
 return songList
```

This code is returning an emptylist of {} meanwhile there list of mediaId is been passed to the query...

but when I try with a single mediaId..like this:

```
val selection = "${MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID} = 38"
```

It works...

I need to get a list of medias...that matches the mediaId

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of media that match the ids, you need to provide the no. of (?) fields to know the SQL database.

i know this is not the best practice, but it's get it job done.

**In Kotlin:**

```
 selectionArgs = songIds as ArrayList<Long>

val questionmark = mutableList<String>()

 for(element in selectionArgs){
   questionmark.add("?")   
}


val selection = "${MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID} IN (${questionmark.joinToString(",")})"
   
 context.contentResolver.query(
        collection,
        projection,
        selection,
        selectionArgs.toTypedArray(),
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER
```